# How to have game objects "snap" into place?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

I have modeled a piece of machinery with multiple parts. I'd like to be able to have the parts "snap" into place while dragging the left mouse button. like in the following video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKz7DdEH9mQ

Here's the code I have:

JS

```
 #pragma strict

 var partnerName = "Hub";
 var closeVPDist = 0.05;
 var moveSpeed = 40.0;
 var rotateSpeed = 90.0;

 var closeColor = Color(1,0,0);

 private var dist = Mathf.Infinity;
 private var normalColor : Color;
 private var partnerGO : GameObject;

 function Start() {
     normalColor = renderer.material.color;
     partnerGO = GameObject.Find(partnerName);
 }

 function OnMouseDrag() {
     var partnerPos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(partnerGO.transform.position);
     var myPos = Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(transform.position);
     dist = Vector2.Distance(partnerPos, myPos);
     renderer.material.color = (dist < closeVPDist) ? closeColor : normalColor;
 }

 function OnMouseUp() {
     if (dist < closeVPDist) {
         transform.parent = partnerGO.transform;
         InstallPart();
     }
 }

 function InstallPart() {
     while (transform.localPosition != Vector3.zero || transform.localRotation != Quaternion.identity) {
         transform.localPosition = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.localPosition, Vector3.zero, Time.deltaTime * moveSpeed);
         transform.localRotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.localRotation, Quaternion.identity, Time.deltaTime * rotateSpeed);
         yield;
     }
 }
```

It works by clicking on the GO and having it go to a "partner" GO... but I'd like to be able to click on the GO and drag it close to the correct place, then have it snap into place.

EDIT:

Adding the following script to each object, combined with the previous script is getting me a little further along. All I have to figure out now is to make them snap back to the original place if not taken close enough to the partner GO. Thoughts?

C#

```
private Vector3 screenPoint;
    private Vector3 offset;

    void OnMouseDown(){
        screenPoint = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(gameObject.transform.position);
        offset = gameObject.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z));
    }

    void OnMouseDrag(){
        Vector3 cursorPoint = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, screenPoint.z);
        Vector3 cursorPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(cursorPoint) + offset;
        transform.position = cursorPosition;
    }
```

Comment: I've implemented this type of functionality in two ways in the past. The first was by storing the original transform of the object and providing the option to snap into the original position (state) when the vector3.distance was within a close enough range. The second way i've done this is by utilizing mapped snapping edges (basically empty gameobjects), which each were mapped to snapping edges of adjacent objects.

Comment: EJSD's answer is perfect.  Go with marker objects (ie, "empty objects", just a plain GameObject in Unity) at the corners.  This is one of the few intelligent comments I have ever seen on this site, nice one EJSD.